# What did Ensign Davies mean when he said “I like to break up married teams” in “Pen Pals”?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the TNG episode [Pen Pals](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pen_Pals), the following exchange takes place:

> **Wesley:** "Ensign Davies?"
>   **Davies:** "You got him."
>   **Wesley:** "Wesley Crusher. I've been put in charge of the planetary geological surveys, and I'd like you on my team."
>   **Davies:** "Sounds great. Who else is on it?"
>   **Wesley:** "I have Prixus and Alans and Hildebrant."
>   **Davies:** "Ah, It's a shame you didn't talk to me first. It's just personal opinion, but I like to break up married teams."
>   **Wesley:** "Oh, I hadn't thought of that."

[Full episode transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/141.htm)

I do not understand what Ensign Davies is trying to say here. What does “I like to break up married teams” mean here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most likely intepretation is that he's suggesting that he prefers for married people to not work with each other on a task. It can create command structure issues, and can introduce risk in that married couples sometimes prioritize each other over the overall team.

In actuality, of course, based on his other actions during the episode, such as convincing Wesley to not do additional scans, this is more likely simply a way to get Wesley to doubt himself, as a power play.

On a side note, the married couple probably is Hildebrant and Alans, both because they're listed together in the description of scientists and because, as noted in [this Teknobabble discussion of the episode](http://www.treknobabble.net/2011/03/next-generation-season-2-pen-pals.html), they start to finish each others' sentences, something common in couples:

> **HILDEBRANDT**: The ore is forming generator strata. 
>   **ALANS**: Which creates a piezoelectric effect. 
>   **PICARD**: In plain English, you're saying the dilithium is causing the geological catastrophe. 
>   **ALANS**: Right, the crystals take the natural radiant heat of the planet 
>   **HILDEBRANDT**: Focus it, and turn it into mechanical energy. 
>   **ALANS**: Which increases tectonic stresses
>  
>   **HILDEBRANDT**: That tear the planet apart.

It is possible that he was referring to "married teams" in a more abstract manner, breaking up teams that have worked extensively with each other without any actual matrimony, which is often invoked for much the same reason (tendency of said team members to prioritize each other over the mission, tendency to back each other up right or wrong).

Comment: Which of the characters could he be referring to? None of them are explicitly stated as being married.

Comment: @Timwi: Honestly, I've found no indication that any of them are married to each other. It's possible that this was part of an earlier script.

Comment: My supposition is that it's Alans and Hildebrant based on an earlier comment by Wesley in the transcript: "I've got Prixus in mineralogy and metallurgy, Alans and Hildebrandt for volcanology and geomechanics. I want Davies for geochemistry, but--" The way he refers to them together even though they're in different areas gives the impression that they're probably a couple.

Comment: It's also just a basic power play / mind games she is playing with Wesely since he is charge

Comment: Ah, and the guys at http://www.treknobabble.net/2011/03/next-generation-season-2-pen-pals.html point out that Hildebrant and Alans start finsihing each others' sentences in the Ready Room.

Comment: Awesome, that’s some strong evidence. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, my first impulse, without context of quotes, was that Davies was being established as the sort of person who likes to create romantic discord (or possibly as a challenge) and that he was lamenting that he wasn't going to get a chance to break anyones' relationships up with his love skills, but that doesn't fit at all. ^_^

Comment: But do they finish each other's... sandwiches?

Comment: Also, given that Davies' comment is right after Wesley lists the other members of the team, it's not a stretch to suppose that two of those three are married to each other (or possible all three - this is the future, after all ;) )

Comment: @Timwi: Is there anything more I can add to this answer for you?

Answer (score 6):

The implication is that Wesley has mentioned some people who're married to each other, either Hildebrant, Alans or Prixus (or heck, maybe all three of them, this is the future after all). Given that Hildebrant is the only female mentioned and that [there are no gay characters in TNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexuality_in_Star_Trek), we can reasonably assume that she's one half of the married couple.

Hildebrant and Alans certainly seem to have a close relationship but it's notable that in the [original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/141.txt), this was described as being *professional* excitement.

> Alans and Hildebrant are playing off each other. Finishing each
>   other's sentences, interrupting. They're excited because they've
>   discovered something new and fascinating, so they're teasing each
>   other.

and

> **ALANS:** *Right, the crystals take the natural radiant heat of the planet*
>
> **HILDEBRANT:** *Focus it, and turn it into mechanical energy.*
>
> **ALANS:** *That increases tectonic stresses*
>
> **HILDEBRANT:** (tapping him on the shoulder) *Excuse me, those plates are mine. Stick to your volcanos. Anyway the stress tears the planet
>   apart.*

**The short answer is that we don't know. None of these characters appear again, nor are their relationships fleshed out in any detail.**

Comment: You make allowances for polyamory in the future, but discount the possibility of a gay couple?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai - I was accounting for the fact that there are [no gay characters in Star Trek TNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexuality_in_Star_Trek)